# Confusion between adjectival phrase and adverbial phrase

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases, adjective-phrases

> I passed the ball to him.

Here, is "to him" modifying the object "ball" or the action verb "passed"?
How can we know for sure?

I have been to several websites before I come here. I did practice to distinguish between adverbial and adjectival prepositional phrases, but I am still not very clear. (If I ask "Who am I passing the ball to?", it feels like "to him" tells us more information about who I am passing the ball to, which would make "to him" an adjective phrase. However, I can also
see "to him" as giving more information about the ball, that the ball is going "to him", making it an adjective).

Answer (score 1):

"To him" is a preposition phrase functioning as a complement.

Compare:

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUNXh.jpg) *I passed the ball to him.*
>
> [2] *I passed him the ball*

In both examples, "the ball" is direct object and "him" is the recipient of the ball. In [2] "him" is indirect object, related directly to the verb "passed", and hence is a core complement.

But in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUNXh.jpg) "him" is related to the verb only indirectly, via the preposition "to", and hence is a non-core complement.

[image]

Comment: I understand that "him" is the indirect object. However, is "to Him" a prepositional phrase? If so, is it an adjective or an adverb phrase and how can we tell?

Comment: "To him" is a preposition phrase because it has "to" as its head word. Its function is that of complement of "passed".

Comment: Very generous making the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

> I passed the ball to him.

Does the phrase modify “ball” or “passed”? Let’s try keeping it hooked to the first:

> I bought the ball to him.

> I painted the ball to him.

> I loved the ball to him.

Hmmmm, those don’t make much sense.  Try keeping the verb:

> I passed the check to him.

> I passed the news to him.

> I passed the question to him.

Those make more sense.  “Passing to him” is a verb phrase.  It is something you can do with a lot of different direct objects.  “The ball to him” is nonsense.

Comment: So, "to" is conjugated to "passed", therefore "to him" has to be an adverbial phrase modifying "passed"? Cool! It is my first time hearing it explained this way.

Comment: @KwanHui No: the PP "to him" is not an adverbial phase. Its function is that of **complement** (not modifier) of "passed", so it cannot possibly be a modifier.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Your diagram says that "to him" is a pp. I guess my question is  Can "to him" be a PP complement that is also modifying the verb "passed" (which would make it an adverbial phrase)? Thank you!

Comment: @KwanHui No, "to him" is a complement, and complements can never be modifiers.

Comment: @BillJ
I have read that "A modifier is a word, phrase, or clause that modifies—that is, gives information about—another word in the same sentence." and that it a modifier can be an adjective, adverb, phrase, or clause. [link](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/modifiers) 

In "I painted the wall red", red is the object complement but it also tells us that the color of the wall is red. Sorry, I still don't feel satisifed. I've just started to learn grammar more seriously. Can you explain in details why or refer me something to read about this topic? Thank you!!!